# data.table::fread error when converting MAF files to data table

Tags: r, bioconductor

I want to merge the 50 MAF files with the sample information so that I can read it as a data.table and subset it.

```
library(maftools)

# Load MAF files
maf = system.file("extdata", list.files(path="mafs/"), package="maftools")

# Load sample information
si <- system.file("extdata", "sample-information.tsv", package="maftools")

d = read.maf(maf=maf, clinicalData=si)
```

Traceback:

```
Error in data.table::fread(file = maf, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,  : 
  File '' does not exist or is non-readable. getwd()=='C:/Users/User/Documents/VanAllen'

> traceback()
3: stop("File '", file, "' does not exist or is non-readable. getwd()=='", 
       getwd(), "'")
2: data.table::fread(file = maf, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
       verbose = FALSE, data.table = TRUE, showProgress = TRUE, 
       header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, skip = "Hugo_Symbol", quote = "")
1: read.maf(maf = maf, clinicalData = si)
1: data.table::fread(input = maf)
```

Maftools documentation:
https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/maftools/man/maftools.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, maf indeed points to no character ( "" ), which of course cannot be read by fread. However when I try

```
fread("R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/maftools/extdata/brca.maf.gz")
```

it works as expected.